# Is there any difference between a GUID and a UUID?

Tags: guid, uuid

I see these two acronyms being thrown around and I was wondering if there are any differences between a GUID and a UUID?

Comment: I can say "GUID", I can't say "UUID".

Comment: I pronounce UUID as "you-wid"

Comment: I say "you-you-I-dee", but I'm not a native speaker...

Comment: UUID specification ([RFC-4122](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4122#section-4.1.1)) says in the abstract: _This specification defines a Uniform Resource Name namespace for UUIDs (Universally Unique IDentifier), also known as GUIDs (Globally Unique IDentifier)_

Comment: @rsp - I lol'd, but then recalled that quantum computing is rapidly becoming a thing, so you might have a point!

Comment: It's funny, in a .mpp file, a generated record had id of "939da69e-8a84-ea11-9a04-d8fc9308ae6b" which is valid in guid world, but looks like it's not a valid uuid!

Comment: The original UUID used the computers MAC address (which is unique) along with motherboard id (also unique), the computers time (not always unique between computers, but does count forward) and finally some random data. This ensured that UUID's generated on different machines could never, ever be the same. However the UUID then exposed some key system information, and that is why it is not used any more, but "just" 32 random bytes instead that has a much higher (but still very low) chance of generating identical identifiers.

Comment: GUID is unique across Globe and UUID is unique across Universe. Choose wisely!

Comment: I am waiting for UUID v100 which is just all random bytes. Here is your PHP implementation `$code=bin2hex(random_bytes(16));$code=substr($code,0,8).'-'.substr($code,8,4).'-'.substr($code,12,4).'-'.substr($code,16,4).'-'.substr($code,20,12);`. Have fun, don't forget to tip your bartenders.

Answer (score 1110, accepted):

The **simple answer** is: **no difference**, they are the same thing.

For most practical purposes, treat them as 16 byte (128 bits) values that are used as a unique identifier.  In Microsoft-speak they are called GUIDs, but call them UUIDs when not using Microsoft-speak.

Even the authors of the UUID specification and Microsoft claim they are synonyms:

- From the introduction to IETF [RFC 4122](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4122) "*A Universally Unique IDentifier (UUID) URN Namespace*": "a Uniform Resource Name namespace for UUIDs (Universally Unique IDentifier), also known as GUIDs (Globally Unique IDentifier)."
- From the [ITU-T Recommendation X.667, ISO/IEC 9834-8:2004 International Standard](http://www.itu.int/ITU-T/studygroups/com17/oid.html): "UUIDs are also known as Globally Unique Identifiers (GUIDs), but this term is not used in this Recommendation."
- And Microsoft even [claims](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc246025%28v=PROT.13%29.aspx) a GUID is specified by the UUID RFC: "In Microsoft Windows programming and in Windows operating systems, a globally unique identifier (GUID), as specified in [RFC4122], is ... The term universally unique identifier (UUID) is sometimes used in Windows protocol specifications as a synonym for GUID."

**Detailed answer**

But the **correct answer** is "it depends". It depends on what the question means when it says "UUID"...

The first part depends on what the asker is thinking when they are saying "UUID".

Microsoft's claim implies that all UUIDs are GUIDs. But are all GUIDs real UUIDs? That is, is the set of all UUIDs just a proper subset of the set of all GUIDs, or is it the exact same set?

Looking at the details of the RFC 4122, there are four different "variants" of UUIDs.  This is mostly because such 16 byte identifiers were in use before those specifications were brought together in the creation of a UUID specification. From section 4.1.1 of [RFC 4122](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4122), the four *variants* of UUID are:

1. Reserved, Network Computing System backward compatibility
2. The *variant* specified in RFC 4122 (of which there are five sub-variants, which are called "versions")
3. Reserved, Microsoft Corporation backward compatibility
4. Reserved for future definition.

According to RFC 4122, all UUID *variants* are "real UUIDs", then all GUIDs are real UUIDs. To the literal question "is there any difference between GUID and UUID" the answer is definitely no for RFC 4122 UUIDs: **no difference** (but subject to the second part below).

But not all GUIDs are *variant* 2 UUIDs (e.g. Microsoft COM has GUIDs which are variant 3 UUIDs). If the question was "is there any difference between GUID and variant 2 UUIDs", then the answer would be yes -- they can be different. Someone asking the question probably doesn't know about *variants* and they might be only thinking of *variant* 2 UUIDs when they say the word "UUID" (e.g. they vaguely know of the MAC address+time and the random number algorithms forms of UUID, which are both *versions* of *variant* 2). In which case, the answer is **yes different**.

So the answer, in part, depends on what the person asking is thinking when they say the word "UUID". Do they mean variant 2 UUID (because that is the only variant they are aware of) or all UUIDs?

The second part depends on which specification being used as the definition of UUID.

If you think that was confusing, read the [ITU-T X.667 ISO/IEC 9834-8:2004](http://www.itu.int/ITU-T/studygroups/com17/oid.html) which is supposed to be aligned and fully technically compatible with [RFC 4122](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4122).  It has an extra sentence in Clause 11.2 that says, "All UUIDs conforming to this Recommendation | International Standard shall have variant bits with bit 7 of octet 7 set to 1 and bit 6 of octet 7 set to 0". Which means that only *variant* 2 UUID conform to that Standard (those two bit values mean *variant* 2). If that is true, then not all GUIDs are conforming ITU-T/ISO/IEC UUIDs, because conformant ITU-T/ISO/IEC UUIDs can only be *variant* 2 values.

Therefore, the real answer also depends on which specification of UUID the question is asking about. Assuming we are clearly talking about all UUIDs and not just variant 2 UUIDs: there is **no difference** between GUID and IETF's UUIDs, but **yes difference** between GUID and *conforming* ITU-T/ISO/IEC's UUIDs!

**Practical notes**

The information above does not go into the details of the UUID/GUID values, or how you get/generate them. But there are two misconceptions about the values that should be cleared up.

**1. Representation of UUID/GUIDs**

Firstly, the same UUID/GUID is a 16 bytes (128 bits) value that can be represented in different ways.

In memory or storage, it can be represented compactly as binary data. For example, it can be represented as an array of sixteen bytes, eight 16-bit words, or four 32-bit integers; signed or unsigned. The endian is significant when using words or integers.

In text or strings, it is commonly represented in hexadecimal with hyphens:

```
hhhhhhhh-hhhh-Yhhh-Xhhh-hhhhhhhhhhhh
```

where h, X and Y are hexadecimal characters.

Some programs might only accept uppercase characters, or only lowercase characters---even though the case is not significant to the value of the UUID/GUID. Some programs might require the hyphens to be omitted or to be present only in those positions---even though the hyphens are not significant to the value of the UUID/GUID.

The positions of the hyphens reflect the time-based version of UUIDs: separating the various time, clock and MAC address fields. Obviously, those fields don't have meaning when it comes to the other version of UUIDs. But, by convention, those positions of the hyphens are still used.

**2. Interpretation of the bytes**

Secondly, always use a library to generate a UUID/GUID. Generating 16 random bytes does not guarantee a valid UUID/GUID. Even when using a version 4 UUID, some of the bytes must have specific values.

In the above hexadecimal string template, three bits of the hexadecimal character in position X encodes the UUID's *variant*. For the variant defined in RFC 4122, X will be either 8, 9, A or B.

If the UUID is an RFC 4122 *variant*, the bits represented by the hexadecimal character in position Y encode its *version*. For example, 4 indicates a version 4.

Randomly generating 16 bytes would not guarantee the bytes would have the correct values in those two fields.

For the full details, see [RFC 4122](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4122#section-4.1.1). But normally you don't need to know their internal structure. If you are just using values you have been given, just treat them as 16 byte (128 bits) values that are used as a unique identifier.

Comment: More informative than chosen answer.  I think the chosen answer is the absolute simplest answer to the question, though.

Comment: The binary encoding table embedded in the answer is very useful. Tnx

Comment: The 'endianness' is very important. If you store the id as bytes you will get different results from GUID and UUID.

Comment: And imagine, beings stuck at a mere 665 upvotes! How could I not upvote this?

Comment: Excellent write up, I would have upvoted, but it's currently at precisely 1024.

Comment: The best answer ever.

Answer (score 729):

GUID is Microsoft's implementation of the UUID standard.

Per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Globally_unique_identifier&oldid=760379804):

> The term GUID usually refers to Microsoft's implementation of the [Universally Unique Identifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) (UUID) standard.

An updated quote from that same Wikipedia article:

> RFC 4122 itself states that UUIDs "are also known as GUIDs". All this suggests that "GUID", while originally referring to a variant of UUID used by Microsoft, has become simply an alternative name for UUID…

Comment: (The G stands for Globally)

Comment: Note that if you want to convert from Microsoft's GUID binary representation to a standard UUID you'll have to flip endianness of the first three (of four) data fields as detailed in the "Binary encoding" section here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier

Comment: This is why astronauts are not allowed to install Windows on the ISS.

Comment: @bdukes Seems Wikipedia has changed what you referred to as their statement. It now reads `The term "GUID" typically refers to various implementations of the universally unique identifier (UUID) standard.`

Comment: Just like Microsoft to take something that someone else came up, which already works perfectly well, develop a competing inferior standard with a new name, and then make us waste some time trying to figure out why...

Comment: Except that isn't what happened, the standard wasn't created until after Microsoft started using GUIDs.

Comment: Up-voting for the simplicity of this answer!

Answer (score 21):

Not really. GUID is more Microsoft-centric whereas UUID is used more widely (e.g., as in the *urn:uuid:* URN scheme, and in CORBA).

Comment: What is the definition and effect of Microsoft-centricity?

Answer (score 9):

GUID has longstanding usage in areas where it isn't necessarily a 128-bit value in the same way as a UUID. For example, the [RSS specification defines GUIDs](http://cyber.law.harvard.edu/rss/rss.html#ltguidgtSubelementOfLtitemgt) to be any string of your choosing, as long as it's unique, with an "isPermalink" attribute to specify that the value you're using is just a permalink back to the item being syndicated.

Comment: lol. Perhaps not the best example given the infamous history of the RSS specification. And it certainly wouldn't be the only thing that the RSS specification got absurdly wrong.

Answer (score 2):

One difference between GUID in SQL Server and UUID in PostgreSQL is letter case; SQL Server outputs upper while PostgreSQL outputs lower.

The hexadecimal values "a" through "f" are output as lower case characters and are case insensitive on input. - [rfc4122#section-3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4122#section-3)