# Whats the difference between a GUID and a UUID?

Tags: guid, uuid

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any difference between a GUID and a UUID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246930/is-there-any-difference-between-a-guid-and-a-uuid)

Whats the difference between a GUID and a UUID, and which should I use for true uniqueness?

Update:
What things do I need for uniqueness too in the algorithm I choose?

```
1) MAC address of network card 
2) 128 bits (isn't 64 bits enough?) 
3) What if I have a multicore machine on the same MAC address. Isn't there a chance of duplicates?
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A GUID is Microsofts implementation of a unique identifier (UUID).

A UUID is defined as

"Universally Unique Identifier (UUID) is an identifier standard used in software construction, standardized by the Open Software Foundation (OSF) as part of the Distributed Computing Environment (DCE)."

From Wikipedia.

If you need to create a new guid/uuid use my website:)

http://www.createnewguid.com

Comment: Does your site create 64 bit or 128 bit GUIDs?

Comment: It uses Guid.NewGuid so thats 128 bit GUIDS!

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.aspx

Comment: This site isn't up anymore. But it's generally not a good idea to get GUIDs from a third-party source like that. You have no idea what algorithm is driving it.

Answer (score 0):

GUIDs are 128-bit UUIDs. You can use GUIDs and be sure of their uniqueness.