# Difference between foreground job and background job

Tags: linux, job-control

In Linux, what is the difference between a foreground job and a background job?

Comment: This is a general reference question. Consult [an encyclopedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Job_control_%28Unix%29) or a book.

Comment: I've read that and there is not info there on this topic.

Comment: Moderator's have decide to close this because _It's difficult to tell what is being asked here._! This really surprises me, because my question is clearly indicated.

Comment: This question was closed (at least in my case) because there is a good answer already in Wikipedia, so you don't need a human being to compose an answer tailored for you. If you don't understand the article or want more information, feel free to ask a more focused question, summarizing what you do understand and indicating what specific point you have a problem with.

Comment: So anything that's explained on Wikipedia is off topic for Stackoverflow?  That [doesn't seem consistent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/246930/is-there-any-difference-between-a-guid-and-a-uuid).  This is a good question; I've been asked this several times by fellow students and coworkers.  I don't see why Stackoverflow shouldn't be used to provide a more clear, concise answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a foreground job, all of your input is directed to the process's `stdin` (including the `SIGINT` that is generated when you press `CTRL-C`, and that's why you can still kill the process if it's in the foreground).

In a background job your input is directed to the shell process instead, and that is why you see the shell prompt and you can execute commands.