# GUID equivalent for Java (Android)

Tags: c#, java, android, guid

Having a bit of experience with `C#` and `SQL`, I've recently discovered that GUIDs are a much better datatype for IDs than integers are. Therefore we're changing alot of our code to start using GUIDs instead of ints, which will hopefully solve alot of referential problems we encounter in our database design.

At the same time, we are exploring the possibility of having a database system on android phones as well. Since both GUIDs and `Java` are brand new to me, I was wondering if there is some sort of equivalent data type in java? (I'm not interested in C# compilers for android by the way). Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Java equivalent is UUID. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html.

Comment: And for the lazy: [Is there any difference between a GUID and a UUID?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/246930/is-there-any-difference-between-a-guid-and-a-uuid)