# Windows 10 generate a UUID for UWP in C++

Tags: win-universal-app

What API is available for generating a UUID in UWP application using C++?

The function UuidCreate is available only for desktop Apps as in :

> > https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379205(v=vs.85).aspx

Thx in advance.

Comment: CoCreateGuid is callable from UWP.

Answer (score 1):

If GUID is sutable alternative for you, you can try [Guid.NewGuid()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.newguid%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396&cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-1).

**EDIT:** Actually, Guid structure is not part of WinRT, so you can't access it via C++. But since you're using C++ , why do you look for UWP specific way to generate UUID? I haven't touched C++ for some while, but I belive you can use any of existing C++ implementation of UUID generator, for example [Boost UUID library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/uuid/uuid.html) or [CoCreateGuid](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms688568%28VS.85%29.aspx) function.

Comment: [They're the same thing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/246930/is-there-any-difference-between-a-guid-and-a-uuid).

Comment: Thx. What header file is this available in? My UWP does not recognize it when i try to use it. Thx.

Comment: Also that page does not provide an example for the C++ language which i am suing. Doesn't that hint that it is not available in C++? Thx.

Comment: Forgive me, I didn't know Guid structure might not be available using C++. Did you tried [CoCreateGuid](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms688568%28VS.85%29.aspx) method?

Comment: Okay seems like indeed CoCreateGuuid is available in UWP. If you update your answer with this, i'll accept the answer(already upvoted). Thx.