# Is there a way to convert a GUID to a UUID in PHP?

Tags: php, converters, guid, uuid

I have GUIDs in this format

```
2k9E4A8DFpFFYsfNkKz5fnx61Ry2xAoO
```

another example:

```
MI5kvu_WGg3MLB4l18UG4oJ63a1H8uF_
```

but I need them in this format:

```
4a9209bd-9252-4914-01a3-24c283062394
```

Is there a way to convert them in PHP? How would you convert them back (from UUID to GUID)?

Comment: they're just strings. just because they're guids doesn't make them magically different. use [string functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php).

Comment: @MarcB the byte order is different https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier#Binary_encoding so they are not just a string.

Comment: what byte order? `oO` isn't exactly a valid hex number. What OP has is a string.

Comment: I see. Here's another example of a GUID I have... `MI5kvu_WGg3MLB4l18UG4oJ63a1H8uF_` and it doesn't look like underscores are part of UUID. :(

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/246930/is-there-any-difference-between-a-guid-and-a-uuid

Comment: @0x13a is it valid to have underscores in UUID/GUID or are the GUIDs I have invalid?

Comment: Looks like a UUID can only contain hexadecimal  characters, but both GUID examples I've given have non-hexadecimal characters.

Comment: What system/software generated the GUID examples you've given? Most documentation I've seen describes UUIDs and GUIDs as being nearly interchangeable. Indeed, Microsoft GUIDs these days are pretty much RFC 4122 UUIDs. UUIDs must be hexadecimal, so if you have something generating GUIDs with different characters, I can either assume they aren't real GUIDs, or they are using a different base (other than base-16, hex) to pack them into a smaller format.

Comment: They are from https://www.comcasttechnologysolutions.com/ I found out that the GUID they are referring to is not a standard GUID and could be any string.

Answer (score -1):

Quick n dirty function to take your original and fudge it into required pattern

```
$guid='2k9E4A8DFpFFYsfNkKz5fnx61Ry2xAoO';

function makeuuid($g){
    $a=array(
        substr($g,0,8),
        substr($g,8,4),
        substr($g,12,4),
        substr($g,16,4),
        substr($g,20,strlen($g))
    );
    return implode('-',$a);
}
echo makeuuid( $guid );

/* outputs: 2k9E4A8D-FpFF-YsfN-kKz5-fnx61Ry2xAoO */
```

Comment: [In its canonical form, a UUID is represented by 32 lowercase hexadecimal digits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Definition)

Comment: So if we were to use a `strtolower()` in the above code, would that resolve the issue and get the proper result?

Comment: Oh I see, because the GUID has non-hexadecimal characters, this script does not work.