# Is UUID really unique?

Tags: uuid

Is UUID really unique? I think that it can be not unique. A UUID is composed of 128 bits, so there are no more than 2^128 different UUIDs. So, if a computer generates (2^128+1) UUIDs, then there must be two UUIDs that are the same.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is a GUID unique 100% of the time?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39771/is-a-guid-unique-100-of-the-time)

Comment: Its a big number - the probability of collisions is very low.

Comment: `there are no more than 2^128 different UUIDs` ... This is a huge number.

Comment: Note that duplicates are only an issue if they're used for the same thing.  I could generate the same GUID for use in my application as you in yours, but they'll never clash since they're in totally different spaces, further reducing the chance that a duplicate actually causes a problem.

Comment: Are UUID and GUID the same thing?

Comment: [Yes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/246930/is-there-any-difference-between-a-guid-and-a-uuid) - I'm an MS-based guy, so GUID comes more naturally to me :)

Comment: Thank you. But, it seems that UUID only guarantees that the probability of generating two same UUIDs is very small. What do many softwares do? Do they just presume that UUIDs are always unique? Do they do any uniqueness check of UUIDs?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How unique is UUID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155008/how-unique-is-uuid)

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption is **correct**.

Due to the [pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle), it is mandatory that (2^128) + 1 UUIDs will have at least one duplicate since there are only (2^128) possibilities.