# Invoke REST API method to update the local admin password

Tags: windows, rest, powershell, scripting, active-directory

I have to write a migration script for Active Directory using PowerShell.
This script will update the password of the local admin of server stored in Pleasant Password Server for KeePass.

First I log into the KeePass using my Windows login credentials and then search the server for which the password needs to be updated.

So, skipping the script for above said functionalities I will start from generating the password:

```cs
function Generate-Password {
    $alphabets = "abcdefghijklmnopqstuvwxyz1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ!@#%^*"

    $char = for ($i = 0; $i -lt $alphabets.Length; $i++) { $alphabets[$i] }

    for ($i = 1; $i -le 16; $i++) {
        Write-Host -NoNewline $(Get-Random $char)
        if ($i -eq 16) { Write-Host `n }
    }
}
$pass = Generate-Password
```

After a password is generated from the above script I want to update the password for the server which I searched.

For example: Find the attachment for [Server Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uK3kV.jpg)

I want to change the password for the above searched server by the function `Generate-Password`.

For this, I used the [REST API method of PPS](https://info.pleasantsolutions.com/Documentation/Pleasant_Password_Server/M._Programmatic_Access/J._Password_Server_REST_API_Documentation):

```
function UpdatePassword {
    $update = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri “$KeepassURL/api/v4/rest/credential/$CredentialID/password/$pass” -Headers $headers -Method Put -ContentType ‘application/json’
}
```

I think I am making some mistakes with the syntax here. How do I pass the generated password ie. `$pass` to the invoked REST method?

Comment: What "server details"? What isn't working the way you expected? *How* is it not working the way you expected?

Comment: Server details means the username = server name ( 01) and the password adjacent to it. Please find the image attached !

Comment: Umm... no, I don't.

Comment: Hi @AnsgarWiechers. Pardon me that you couldn't find the attached image. Have edited the question. Now you can see the link "Server Details" as an attached image.
Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

The documentation you referenced says:

> ```
> PUT credential/:id        ** Update a credential **
> Method                    PUT
> Requires Authentication?  Yes
>
> Parameters
> id                        GUID for credential
>
> Input type                Credential
> Result type               None
> ```

and the documentation of the [`Credential`](https://info.pleasantsolutions.com/Documentation/Pleasant_Password_Server/M._Programmatic_Access/J._Password_Server_REST_API_Documentation/Service_Models#SCredential) input type shows this example JSON document:

> ```
> Example Credential (JSON)
>
> {
>     Id: "2b45438a-2f4a-4d96-9ba9-058ea54252fb"
>     Name: "Credential 0"
>     Username: "Credential 0"
>     Password: null
>     Url: ""
>     Notes: ""
>     GroupId: "cfb2c08e-e990-43b7-99d1-c8e23e0ae00e"
>     Created: "2013-11-18T10:14:27.8218898-07:00"
>     Modified: "2015-06-01T13:26:12.336084-06:00"
>     Expires: null
>     ...
> }
> ```

So you probably need to do something like this:

```
$CredentialID = '2b45438a-2f4a-4d96-9ba9-058ea54252fb'
$uri  = "$KeepassURL/api/v4/rest/credential/$CredentialID"
$type = 'application/json'
$body = @{
    'Id'       = $CredentialID
    'Name'     = 'Credential 0'
    'Username' = 'Credential 0'
    'Password' = $pass
    ...
}

Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Put -Headers $headers -Body $body -ContentType $type
```

assuming that you're passing an already acquired authorization token via `$headers`.

Untested, though, and I'm not quite sure if you need all key/value pairs in the body or just the relevant ones, so you'll need to play around with it a little.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
The variable '$CredentialID' needs GUID to proceed the script further. But the client ( KeePass ) shows only the 'UUID' of the machine and not the GUID. Would I need another script to access the GUID first for the server?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246930/is-there-any-difference-between-a-guid-and-a-uuid

Comment: @PranjalKaushik Any particular reason why you unaccepted this answer?