# Control Windows 10's "Power Mode" programmatically

Tags: c++, .net, winapi

### Background

Hi. I have an SB2 (Surface Book 2), and I'm one of the unlucky users who are facing the [infamous 0.4GHz throttling problem](https://www.reddit.com/r/Surface/comments/94uac9/lets_talk_about_the_sb2_infamous_04ghz_throttling/) that is plaguing many of the SB2 machines. The problem is that the SB2 suddenly, and very frequently depending on the ambient temperature, throttles heavily from a boost of 4GHz to 0.4GHz and hangs in there for a minute or two (this causes a severe slow-down of the whole laptop). This is extremely frustrating and almost makes the machine unusable for even the simplest of workloads.

Microsoft apparently [stated that it fixed the problem](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4055398/surface-book-2-update-history) in the October 2019 update, but I and several other users are still facing it. I'm very positive my machine is up to date, and I even manually installed all the latest Surface Book 2 firmware updates.

Here's a capture of the CPU state when the problem is happening:
[image: throttling-image]

As you can see, the temperature of the unit itself isn't high at all, but CPU is throttling at 0.4GHz exactly.

More links about this: [1](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/surface/forum/surfbook2-surfperf/surface-book-2-throttles-excessively-often-down-to/8d5e9096-6735-429f-b0ae-012584de1516) [2](https://www.reddit.com/r/Surface/comments/dbbs8k/surface_book_2_throttles_frequently_but_changing/)

### Workarounds

I tried pretty much EVERYTHING. Undervolting until freezing screens, disabling BD PROCHOT, disabling power throttling in GPE, messing up with the registry, tuning several CPU/GPU settings. Nothing worked.

You can do only 2 things when the throttling starts:

1. Wait for it to finish (usually takes a minute or two).
2. Change the [Power Mode in windows 10](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/desktop/images/power-slider.png). It doesn't even matter if you're changing it from "Best performance" to "Best battery life", what matters is that you change it. As soon as you do, throttling completely stops in a couple seconds. This is the only manual solution that worked.

### Question

In practice, changing this slider each 10 seconds no matter how heavy the workload is, indefinitely lead to a smooth experience without throttling. Of course, this isn't a feasible workaround by hand.

In theory, I thought that if I could find a way to control this mode programmatically, I might be able to wish this problem goodbye by switching power modes every 10 seconds or so.

I don't mind if it's in win32 (winapi) or a .net thing. I looked a lot, found [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/power/power-management-functions) about power management, but it seems there's no interface for setting in win32. I could have overlooked it, so here's my question:

**Is there any way at all to control the Power Mode in Windows 10 programmatically?**

Comment: Can changing between "High performance" and "Balanced" solve this problem? See [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sh02E.png).

Comment: @str The OP is trying to change that setting **programmatically**. They already know how to do it manually.

Comment: I'm well aware what a power plan is. Changing the power mode isn't what solves the problem, but the throttling pauses *for some time* as a side effect when I change the mode. I'm trying to replicate that programmatically as I said.

Comment: @mrahhal Yes, maybe you can use `RegSetValueEx` to modify the corresponding key value. And this requires registry permissions.

Comment: @StriveSun-MSFT Any idea what's the registry key and values for the power mode? I can't seem to find this anywhere. (I found power schemes, but those are related to the general power plan, not the power mode)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

OK...  I've been wanting command line or programmatic access to adjust the power slider for a while, and I've run across this post multiple times when looking into it.  I'm surprised no one else has bothered to figure it out.  I worked it out myself today, motivated by the fact that Windows 11 appears to have removed the power slider from the taskbar and you have to go digging into the Settings app to adjust it.

As previously discussed, in the registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power\User\PowerSchemes you can find values "ActiveOverlayAcPowerScheme" and "ActiveOverlayDcPowerScheme" which record the current values of the slider for AC power and battery power, respectively.  However, changing these values is not sufficient to adjust the power slider or the system's mode of operation.

Turns out there is an undocumented method in C:\Windows\System32\powrprof.dll called PowerSetActiveOverlayScheme.  It takes a single parameter.  I "guessed" that it would take a GUID in the same manner that PowerSetActiveScheme does, and it seems to work.

*Note — Using an undocumented API is unsupported by Microsoft.  This method may break in future Windows releases.  It can be used for personal tinkering but I would not suggest using it in any actual production projects.*

Here is the C# PInvoke signature:

```
[DllImportAttribute("powrprof.dll", EntryPoint = "PowerSetActiveOverlayScheme")]
public static extern uint PowerSetActiveOverlayScheme(Guid OverlaySchemeGuid);
```

It returns zero on success and non-zero on failure.

Calling it is as simple as:

```
PowerSetActiveOverlayScheme(new Guid("ded574b5-45a0-4f42-8737-46345c09c238"));
```

It has immediate effect.  This particular GUID moved the slider all the way to the right for me and also updated the "ActiveOverlayAcPowerScheme" value in the registry.  Using a GUID of all zeros reset the slider to the middle value.  You can see what GUID options are available by just observing the values that show up in the registry when you set the power slider to different positions.

There are two methods that can be used to read the current position of the slider.  I'm not sure what the difference between them is, they returned the same value each time in my testing.

```
[DllImportAttribute("powrprof.dll", EntryPoint = "PowerGetActualOverlayScheme")]
public static extern uint PowerGetActualOverlayScheme(out Guid ActualOverlayGuid);

[DllImportAttribute("powrprof.dll", EntryPoint = "PowerGetEffectiveOverlayScheme")]
public static extern uint PowerGetEffectiveOverlayScheme(out Guid EffectiveOverlayGuid);
```

They also return zero on success and non-zero on failure.  They can be called like...

```
if (PowerGetEffectiveOverlayScheme(out Guid activeScheme) == 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine(activeScheme);
}
```

There is one more method called "PowerGetOverlaySchemes", which I presume can be used to fetch a list of available GUIDs that could be used.  It appears to take three parameters and I haven't bothered with figuring it out.

I created a command-line program which can be used to set the power mode, and it can be found at https://github.com/AaronKelley/PowerMode.

Comment: Wow! Good work! Since then I've been using another machine, but I'll be trying this and see if it actually resolves my problem. Will report back when I do.

Comment: Played around with it some more this afternoon.  I am wondering if, when you get a chance to mess with this, if you can check on this behavior for me...  I want to see if it is just strange on my system or if this is the "normal" behavior.

The GUID "3af9B8d9-7c97-431d-ad78-34a8bfea439f" is *supposed* to be for "better performance", the middle option of the slider.  When I set this value, on AC power the slider goes to "best performance" and on battery power it goes to "battery saver".  To set it to "better performance" I have to use an all-zero GUID.

The other values work as expected.

Comment: That's strange. Seems to be working consistently with me, it sets it to "Better Performance" (I have stable Windows 10).

Comment: Thanks for confirming.  Not sure what's going on with my system (also Windows 10 in this case).  Maybe it's because of an OEM override.  (I know there is some capability for OEMs to set the power mode behaviors.)  I posted the command-line tool and set it up such that you can put custom GUIDs in the config file if necessary.

Comment: Please read [this article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20150922-00/?p=91541) before using this method. No one can guarantee that this method will always be reliable. I do not recommend that this answer be marked, it can only be used as a reference.

Comment: And looking for undocumented api as a solution itself is a wrong direction!!!

Comment: I'd love to know what a "right direction" would be here, since Microsoft hasn't made an API available for this and they have zero documentation on adjusting the power mode without direct user input.  I spent quite a bit of time searching for it; the choices are basically "use the undocumented API" or "it can't be done".  I didn't make this clear in the post, but it should understood that this is a "hack" of sorts and it may obviously may break in future versions of Windows.  It works in Windows 10 and 11 so we are good for a while.

Comment: Before providing such methods, shouldn't you first consider why Microsoft does not provide such an interface. It's best to prompt other people later in the beginning of the answer. **This method is more like a "hack". Please don't use it in actual projects.**

Comment: I will edit the answer to provide a "disclaimer" or sorts at the top.

Answer (score 6):

[Aaron's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68318696/2010258) is awesome work, helped me massively, thank you.

If you're anything like me and

1. don't have Visual Studio at the ready to compile his tool for yourself and/or
2. don't necessarily want to run an arbitrary executable file off of GitHub (no offence),

you can use Python (3, in this case) to accomplish the same thing.

For completeness' sake, I'll copy over the disclaimer:

> Note — Using an undocumented API is unsupported by Microsoft. This method may break in future Windows releases. It can be used for personal tinkering but I would not suggest using it in any actual production projects.

Please also note, that the following is just basic proof-of-concept code!

Getting the currently active Byte Sequence:

```py
import ctypes

output_buffer = ctypes.create_string_buffer(b"",16)

ctypes.windll.powrprof.PowerGetEffectiveOverlayScheme(output_buffer)
print("Current Effective Byte Sequence: " + output_buffer.value.hex())

ctypes.windll.powrprof.PowerGetActualOverlayScheme(output_buffer)
print("Current Actual Byte Sequence: " + output_buffer.value.hex())
```

On my system, this results in the following values:

| Mode | Byte Sequence |
| --- | --- |
| Better Battery | `77c71c9647259d4f81747d86181b8a7a` |
| Better Performance | `00000000000000000000000000000000` |
| Best Performance | `b574d5dea045424f873746345c09c238` |

Apparently Aaron's and my system [share the same peculiarity](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4647297/aaron), where the "Better Performance" Byte Sequence is just all zeros (as opposed to the "expected" value of `3af9B8d9-7c97-431d-ad78-34a8bfea439f`).

Please note, that the Byte Sequence `77c71c9647259d4f81747d86181b8a7a` is equivalent to the GUID `961cc777-2547-4f9d-8174-7d86181b8a7a` and `b574d5dea045424f873746345c09c238` represents `ded574b5-45a0-4f42-8737-46345c09c238`.

This stems from the the fact that GUIDs are written down differently than how they're actually represented in memory. (If we assume a GUID's bytes to be written as `ABCD-EF-GH-IJ-KLMN` its Byte Sequence representation ends up being `DCBAFEHGIJKLMN`). See https://stackoverflow.com/a/6953207 (particularly the pararaph and table under "Binary encodings could differ") and/or https://uuid.ramsey.dev/en/latest/nonstandard/guid.html if you want to know more.

Setting a value (for "Better Battery" in this example) works as follows:

```py
import ctypes

modes = {
    "better_battery":     "77c71c9647259d4f81747d86181b8a7a",
    "better_performance": "00000000000000000000000000000000",
    "best_performance":   "b574d5dea045424f873746345c09c238"
}

ctypes.windll.powrprof.PowerSetActiveOverlayScheme(bytes.fromhex(modes["better_battery"]))
```

For me, this was a nice opportunity to experiment with Python's `ctypes` :).

Answer (score 2):

Here is a PowerShell version that sets up a scheduled task to toggle the power overlay every minute. It is based off the godsend answers of [Michael](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68575246/5412895) and [Aaron](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68318696/5412895).

The CPU throttling issue has plagued me on multiple Lenovo X1 Yoga laptops (Gen2 and Gen4 models).

```powershell
# Toggle power mode away from and then back to effective overlay 
$togglePowerOverlay = {
    $function = @'
    [DllImport("powrprof.dll", EntryPoint="PowerSetActiveOverlayScheme")]
    public static extern int PowerSetActiveOverlayScheme(Guid OverlaySchemeGuid);
    [DllImport("powrprof.dll", EntryPoint="PowerGetActualOverlayScheme")]
    public static extern int PowerGetActualOverlayScheme(out Guid ActualOverlayGuid);
    [DllImport("powrprof.dll", EntryPoint="PowerGetEffectiveOverlayScheme")]
    public static extern int PowerGetEffectiveOverlayScheme(out Guid EffectiveOverlayGuid);
'@
    $power = Add-Type -MemberDefinition $function -Name "Power" -PassThru -Namespace System.Runtime.InteropServices
    
    $modes = @{
        "better_battery"     = [guid] "961cc777-2547-4f9d-8174-7d86181b8a7a";
        "better_performance" = [guid] "00000000000000000000000000000000";
        "best_performance"   = [guid] "ded574b5-45a0-4f42-8737-46345c09c238"
    }
    
    $actualOverlayGuid = [Guid]::NewGuid()
    $ret = $power::PowerGetActualOverlayScheme([ref]$actualOverlayGuid)
    if ($ret -eq 0) {
        "Actual power overlay scheme: $($($modes.GetEnumerator()|where {$_.value -eq  $actualOverlayGuid}).Key)." | Write-Host
    }
    
    $effectiveOverlayGuid = [Guid]::NewGuid()
    $ret = $power::PowerGetEffectiveOverlayScheme([ref]$effectiveOverlayGuid)
    
    if ($ret -eq 0) {        
        "Effective power overlay scheme: $($($modes.GetEnumerator() | where { $_.value -eq  $effectiveOverlayGuid }).Key)." | Write-Host
        
        $toggleOverlayGuid = if ($effectiveOverlayGuid -ne $modes["best_performance"]) { $modes["best_performance"] } else { $modes["better_performance"] }     
        
        # Toggle Power Mode
        $ret = $power::PowerSetActiveOverlayScheme($toggleOverlayGuid)
        if ($ret -eq 0) {
            "Toggled power overlay scheme to: $($($modes.GetEnumerator()| where { $_.value -eq  $toggleOverlayGuid }).Key)." | Write-Host
        }

        $ret = $power::PowerSetActiveOverlayScheme($effectiveOverlayGuid)
        if ($ret -eq 0) {
            "Toggled power overlay scheme back to: $($($modes.GetEnumerator()|where {$_.value -eq  $effectiveOverlayGuid }).Key)." | Write-Host
        }
    }
    else {
        "Failed to toggle active power overlay scheme." | Write-Host      
    }
}

# Execute the above
& $togglePowerOverlay
```

Create a scheduled job that runs the above script every minute:

- Note that Register-ScheduledJob only works with Windows PowerShell, not PowerShell Core
- I couldn't get the job to start without using the System principal. Otherwise gets stuck indefinitely in Task Scheduler with "The task has not run yet. (0x41303)".
- Get-Job will show the job in Windows PowerShell, but Receive-Job doesn't return anything even though there is job output in dir $env:UserProfile\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\PowerShell\ScheduledJobs$taskName\Output. This might be due to running as System while trying to Receive-Job as another user?
- I wish -MaxResultCount 0 was supported to hide the job in Get-Job, but alas it is not.
- You can see the task in Windows Task Scheduler under Task Scheduler Library path \Microsoft\Windows\PowerShell\ScheduledJobs
- It was necessary to have two script blocks, one as command and one as arguments (that gets serialized/deserialized as a string) because PowerShell script blocks use dynamic closures instead of lexical closures and thus referencing one script block from another when creating a new runspace is not readily possible.
- The min interval for scheduled tasks is 1 minute. If it turns out that more frequent toggling is needed, might just add a loop in the toggling code and schedule the task only for startup or login.

```powershell
$registerJob = {
    param($script)
    $taskName = "FixCpuThrottling"
    Unregister-ScheduledJob -Name $taskName -ErrorAction Ignore
    $job = Register-ScheduledJob -Name $taskName -ScriptBlock $([scriptblock]::create($script)) -RunEvery $([TimeSpan]::FromMinutes(1)) -MaxResultCount 1
    $psSobsSchedulerPath = "\Microsoft\Windows\PowerShell\ScheduledJobs";
    $principal = New-ScheduledTaskPrincipal -UserId SYSTEM -LogonType ServiceAccount 
    $someResult = Set-ScheduledTask -TaskPath $psSobsSchedulerPath -TaskName $taskName -Principal $principal
}

# Run as Administrator needed in order to call Register-ScheduledJob
powershell.exe -command $registerJob -args $togglePowerOverlay
```

To stop and remove the scheduled job (must use Windows PowerShell):

```powershelll
$taskName = "FixCpuThrottling"
Unregister-ScheduledJob -Name $taskName-ErrorAction Ignore
```