# Postman dynamic variables, difference between $guid and $randomUUID

Tags: postman

[Their doc](https://learning.postman.com/docs/writing-scripts/script-references/variables-list/) suggests two types,

- `$guid    A uuid-v4 style guid`
- `$randomUUID  A random 36-character UUID`

Is there a difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes they are different in terms of generation. For purpose they are same.

Here you may check:
https://www.google.com/search?q=uuid+vs+guid

Also this answer may help:
[Is there any difference between a GUID and a UUID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246930/is-there-any-difference-between-a-guid-and-a-uuid)